# Grouping data from different fields in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, view, grouping

I have a bit of an issue, and I’m wondering if anyone can be of assistance…
I am trying to group data that is recorded in different fields, but is identical in some cases…..let me explain:
In my Vehicle_Schedule table, I have a separate field for “Driver” and another for “Helper”. 
When employees are reporting to work, their assignments can interchange, so one might be designated as the “Driver” one day, only to be designated as the “Helper” on the next.
I need to be able to produce various reports that will summarize the result by employee…
Currently, I am running 2 separate reports, one for “Driver” and another for “Helper”, and combining the data in Excel, which is tedious and I do believe there must be a way in Crystal to do it, whether it is a sub report or a view….
Here is a quick sample of what I’m trying to accomplish:

Date    Trip ID Driver  Helper  Time to complete
15-Oct  100 Joe Sam 30 minutes
16-Oct  101 Eric    Sam 20 minutes
17-Oct  102 Sam Joe 20 minues
18-Oct  103 Dave    Sam 20 minutes
19-Oct  104 Joe Dave    10 minutes
20-Oct  105 Dave    Sam 20 minutes

Based on this example, the report should be able to provide the following results:

```
    Employee        Avg time to complete        
    Joe     (30+20+10)/3=20 (Trips 100,102 and 104) 
    Eric        20  Trip 101    
    Sam     (30+20+20+20+20)/5=22   (Trips 100,101,102,103,105) 
    Dave        (20+10+20)/3=16.66  (Trips 103,104,105)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated….

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what your database/datasource is, but all you need to do is select the two tables in your database expert and link them on the same field (I'm guessing the employee name). Then in your report, you group by the employee name and in the detail section you can then list your data. Then you can summarize the trip data and either show totals, averages, or whatever else you want. If you need more help than that I suggest you tell us more about your database and tables.